# Slow for loop iteration in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

So I'm making a batch script and I need to run a powershell command inside a for but it's running really slow, I don't know how to make it more efficient, I'm very new in this stuff. Here's part of my code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in (myfile.txt) do (
       powershell -command '%%G' -replace ',+', ' ' >> newfile.txt
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you just dont run the batch fully as powershell?

Comment: The reason it runs slow is becuase it has to load powershell application each time. This means loading DLL and files into memory every single time you call it. If this command was fully in powershell instead of calling the application everytime in a for loop from shell then it would run much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you are new to this. It's really important you get some ramp up on the topic. Using either all the free stuff Microsoft offers ([Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/training-topics/powershell#!lang=1033) or [MS Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=powershell&lang-en=true) or [TechNet Virtual Labs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/my-virtual-labs) or [labsondemand](https://labondemand.com/Event/MSHandsOnLabs/Home)), or [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell) or at minimum review the help files first. There are lots of free eBooks as well and step by step blogs.

As the others have said, why not just do this in PS directly, to read and process the file. Though you don't have to, you can call a .ps1 from a .bat/.cmd/.vbs, etc., but you don't have to use it to process what PS can do.

```
# Giving a target file to be modified
# Check what is in the file
# Note: I am using Get-Content here, but if you have a .csv, then use the *csv* cmdlets

Get-Content -Path 'd:\temp\myfile.txt'

# Results

LIC,+CLIENT
12345,+Client1
54321,+Client2
34251,+Client3


# Test new file path

Test-Path -Path 'd:\temp\newfile.txt'

# Results

False

# Decide what to replace, code the replace 
# and see what the new file content will look like when replaced

Get-Content -Path 'd:\temp\myfile.txt' | 
ForEach{$_ -replace '\,\+',' '}

# Results

LIC CLIENT
12345 Client1
54321 Client2
34251 Client3

# Modify to send to a new file.
Get-Content -Path 'd:\temp\myfile.txt' | 
ForEach{
    $_ -replace '\,\+',' ' | 
    Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\newfile.txt' -Append
}

# Results 
Test-Path -Path 'd:\temp\newfile.txt'
True

Get-Content -Path 'd:\temp\newfile.txt'

# Results, should be the same as screen output.

LIC CLIENT
12345 Client1
54321 Client2
34251 Client3
```

Comment: Thanks, this solve it. I was trying to make this whole thing in a batch script but I guess is more efficient in PS.

Comment: No worries, we all have run into this stuff in the beginning, at one point or the other with stuff we've had to do  / learn about.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in your comment that you were trying to do it all in a batch script here is the basic syntax for string replacement.  You have to first assign the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable before you can do any string replacement. You would also need to enable delayed expansion because you are manipulating a variable inside a parentheses code block.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /f "delims=" %%G in (myfile.txt) do (
    set "line=%%G"
    echo !line:+= !
)
)>newfile.txt
```

You could also do this without delayed expansion by using `CALL ECHO`

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%G in (myfile.txt) do (
    set "line=%%G"
    CALL echo %%line:+= %%
)
)>newfile.txt
```

Comment: I found out this later reading some other post here but I didn't know why they use delayed expansion or CALL ECHO. Now I know, thanks. I'm a linux/unix person, so I'm pretty unfamiliar with this.